# Slow Internet connection

Tags: internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My internet speed became slow at night](https://superuser.com/questions/249972/my-internet-speed-became-slow-at-night)

My internet connectivity from my Laptop slowed down overnight. I have no clue as what had happened. I was able to download at 300kbps the day before yesterday. And from yesterday on, my internet has been slow. My download speed is at 25kbps. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

I am using wireless connection on my Sony Vaio.
I am not sure what else info I need to give as this is my first time to post a question here..

Comment: "Yes, someone can help you resolve this, just not here". Have you called your ISP? Perhaps try some things and come back and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably automatic updates from something (Windows isn't the only place where automatic updates are possible; Adobe Reader, Firefox, Opera, iTunes, and many other applications do this).

If you have music sharing software or some bittorrent transfers active, then these can eat up a lot of bandwidth when least suspected as well.

Also, since you're using a Sony computer, you may have their highly controversial root-kit running.  If this is the case, then Sony (or someone else who knows how to exploit it) may be using the root-kit to audit all your MP3s to determine if you're pirating music (I'm not sure how they differentiate between a pirated MP3 or a backup of a legitimately purchased original CD that was saved in MP3 format, but they have advanced algorithms for this according to the guy at their 1-800 number I called about this back when their root-kit was new) -- at least that's my understanding of the purpose of the Sony root-kit (to catch MP3 pirates).

There could be other SpyWare or viruses as well.  These two free tools are excellent, and I believe they can detect and remove Sony's root-kit too:

MalwareBytes
  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

SpyBot - Search & Destroy
  http://security.kolla.de/

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, the problem could be a. your laptop, b. your LAN including wireless connection or c. your ISP. You need to systematically eliminate each area until you figure out where your problem is. You can eliminate your laptop by trying it on another network or by getting another computer to try on yours. You can eliminate your LAN by plugging your laptop directly into your Internet modem/router. For your Internet Connection, this [packet loss resource page](http://www.hostmycalls.com/packet-loss/) has a free packet loss test that will determine whether you have a problem with your Internet connection. If you do, it will determine whether the problem is specific to your location or something within the ISP. It also has a troubleshooting page which gives troubleshooting tips similar to these here except in more detail.